# Unable to read the Gmail INBOX from the java code using POP API .. giving an error java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect error

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

```
props.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.pop3.user", "xxx@gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory", 995);
        props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.pop3.port", 995);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("xxx",
                                "xxx");
                    }
                });
        try {
            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
            store.connect("pop.gmail.com", "xxxxx", "xxx");
            Folder fldr = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            fldr.open(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
            int count = fldr.getMessageCount();
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc + " error");
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Error:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect error

As I have added Proxy setting in this application
    And set firewalls off. Still its is giving the above error.

Answer (score -1):

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has simpler code for [connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail), as well as [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug) and [instructions for using proxy servers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).